# String formatting in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a simple query.

How can I format the text in cells in my Workbook.

If my cell has text ABC, I want it in the format 'ABC'. Is there any formula for this?

I am using Excel 2010.
I cannot do find and replace as all the values I want to alter are unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Edit the cell or column you need to format
- choose format cell
- Select Custom from the bottom
- Use the formula '@' .

@ represents your text

Comment: Rare information! Relearned this from a few years ago! Hard to find on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Use CONCATENATE. For example if the cell is A1 then the function would be:

```
=CONCATENATE("'", A1, "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add value to lgor's answer as He's already made the point.

> "@" represents the text.

Just go to format cells > custom and surround the `@` with two Apostrophes, like: `'@'` and it will work.